# Alien sent to earth followed by a skeleton and robot from same planet

Tags: story-identification, books

A few years ago, I remember reading a book where some kind of alien is sent to Earth and is followed by a skeleton and robot from the same planet. I also recall there being a monkey that used guns. Does anybody have any idea what book this is?

Comment: If He-Man is the alien and Skeletor is the skeleton, then this sounds almost like *Masters of the Universe*.

Comment: @Praxis Do you know if Masters of the Universe involved a robot or a monkey with guns?

Comment: It isn't *Masters*, sorry to say.  (Was only a joke based on some common elements!)  ;-)